# How to use an SSL cert in a Java program

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to query LDAP over an SSL connection.  I was sent a certificate and ran:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias www.the-domain.com -file the-cert.der -keystore store.jks
```

I then pointed my Java program at the cert by adding the following to the run configuration in Intellij:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/store.jks
```

I get a socket closed exception when I try to connect.  Did I miss a step?

Here is the standard out, slightly modified to remove IP info:

```
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: <ip:port>; socket closed
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:419)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:340)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:192)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2694)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:293)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:82)
at LDAPTool.main(LDAPTool.java:35)
```

Comment: Should the connection using mutual authentication? If so, you're half way there.

Comment: please post the complete exception including message and stacktrace.

Comment: added. laz I dont know what that is.  Was told to use the cert the other app provided.  Were my steps to set up the keystore and configure my tool correct?

Comment: also, i put the cert in the KS using a domain, but I am accessing the server by ip in my code.  Does that matter?  Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what my issue was.  I didn't set up my environment correctly.

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
```

when using ssl evidently you need to specify the security protocol, which makes sense....